# Critique request: logo for a health product

Tags: logo, critique

I designed this logo for a product called "Sahha", it uses music to relieve different ailments. The idea behind the logo is a hummingbird that resembles a sound control icon. I’d like to receive critiques and advice about:

1. Color: Is it a good idea to go with gradients? I think the palette is quite nice but I’m still not entirely sure, you guys think I should use colors that relate more to medicine (maybe only green and blue)?
2. Shape: the beak is a bit sharp, does it look aggressive? Does it look like what was intended (sound icon)?
3. Font: I'm using roboto condensed, but I’d like to try other fonts, any recommendation?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: aesthetically, I think there's a lot of good here. The gradient doesn't feel gratuitous. If anything, I'd suggest trying a version with much thinner sound waves. The hummingbird is such a nice illustration that the sound waves seem to be overbearing in relation. Perhaps the width of the waves could mirror the width of the beak.

Answer (score 5):

Over all I like it.

I think the beak is perhaps a bit sharp. Rounding it would soften the image. In fact, the head seems *slightly* too large. However, if you were following the sides of the tail up to define the head shape, I can see that.

Concerning the type.... There's such a beautiful opportunity being missed to design the A - double H - A combination, rather than simply typing something.

I don't see an issue with the gradients or palette, but I would also design a flat color version to be thorough. Gradients can present some issues in some use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your logo looks really good; I think the hummingbird as a sound icon is very clever. Here's a few ideas to strengthen the design a bit.

1. **Color:** I really like the gradient and the color scheme. You can play around with flat colors (as I have in my example) to see if you like it better, but either way is fine.
2. **Shape:**

   - The beak is sharp, but it does get your attention, which could be a good thing.
   - One thing I would suggest is rotate your hummingbird 90 degrees, so that you can make the sound control icon connection more clear; I wouldn't have noticed it if you hadn't mentioned it before.
   - As DA01 suggested, the waves could be a bit thinner.
   - It could just be me, but the tail looks a little fat for a hummingbird. The head does too, but I understand it's difficult to keep it looking like a sound icon. The long beak helps with the hummingbird idea, though.
3. **Font:** I like Roboto, but perhaps you could look at [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) or [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) to see if there's one you like better? (Make sure the font you choose has an open license, though.)

[image: My example]

*Here's my example, sorry it's so pixelated, I just threw it together in the Gimp. I would recommend thinning out the tail at least, but Gimp wouldn't let me do that very easily.*

Comment: Brilliant tweak, @Cullenj

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually nice simple idea - humming/sound device + medical treatment

Although the hummingbird looks a bit like a more robust species, like a Kingfisher or a Kookaburra.

A medical treatment/instrument of this type might like to evoke "accuracy" and "delicate" maybe with a more feminine appeal (female client base?) - Hummingbirds are the butterfly's of the bird family, they are around 5cm long - Maybe your logo could evoke its fragility also.

Not to directly copy any of the many Hummingbird logos already out there, there are many examples of more refined Hummingbird shape, especially viewed from side on.

Answer (score 0):

**Shape**

I like yours a lot. The only thing I'd say is regarding shape. You mention the beak is pointy, and it is. I like it like that. What I don't like is that the sound waves don't terminate at an angle. The beak and the wings are much sharper. I like the sharper look and think the sound waves should match.

**Gradient**

Gradient is fine, especially since the colors are somewhat similar so you won't have too much difficulty using it on different backgrounds.